# Error installing node js on Amazon EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yum

I am trying to install Node Js and npm on my new Amazon EC2 instance but I can't succeed in doing so.

I am referring to the official doc : https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

I run

```
sudo curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | bash -
```

But I am getting an error :

```
error: can't create transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (Permission denied)
```

I have seen similar case problems that were solved by using sudo but even using sudo I can't get it.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: maybe something else is holding the rpm database, try remove /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock (with root or sudo) and retry

Comment: It does not work. I get an error telling me that the /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock does not exist.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, did you find any solution ? By the way installing from source works (curl, ./configure, sudo make install, see https://github.com/nodejs/node)

Answer (score 2):

Adding a **sudo** right before **bash** did it for me

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_5.x |sudo bash -
```

Then

```
sudo yum install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command and you'll be good to go:

```
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash -
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).